# filtering nodes in a block per term in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

i want to make something like the blocks on [www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/art](http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/art) that is the content of the block changes per term ( display featured node of the selected term only)

i'm using views 3 and manged to do the block but i'm facing difficulties in applying the dynamic filters ..

any idea on how to do that? am sure i'm just missing a small configuration :)
thx in advance

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view's edit page, find "Contextual filters" under "Advanced" section, then click "Add"

1- Form the list, choose "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" and click "Apply"

2- Setup the configuration you need then click "Apply"

Now you are able to filter the results by the term id. for example "your-page/3, your-page/4, your-page/15) where (3, 4 and 15) are term IDs.

**EDIT:**
Well, In filter settings form under `When the filter value is NOT available`, choose `Provide default value` then `Raw value from URL` and `Path component` choose `3` (We had to choose the number `3`, because the pages you are trying to show them into are under `taxonomy/term/[tid]`)

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: thx for the quick answer .. that works if i filter in the admin view configuration using the term id but not on the website where alias path used (the pattern is as follows: {discover/[vocabulary]/[term]). my website is as follows: user click on taxonomy term from the menu then he get a page where he can view 2 blocks, 1st includes 3 featured nodes that has that term , 2nd is the latest 6 nodes under that term.   any idea ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly recheck and let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: still same issue.. the block still shows empty on the pages :http://www.example.com/discover/[vocabulary]/[term]

Comment: If you like, you can send me a temp admin account to your website so I can take a closer look. You can find my email in my profile page.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot view ur email on your profile page but there is a FB account .. is it ok if i msg u there ??

Comment: Surely no problem. Also tell me where to view my messages! :)

Comment: lol .. i thought u r kidding :) ..it's the "2 small blurbs" icon on the top left on the right of the facebook logo

Comment: Email me `m.reda[at]m-e-s-c[dot]com` :) Still can't find it... -Muhammad

Comment: great :)!! its working now perfectly.. just last thing.. can we make the block displays latest 3 sticky nodes rather than empty if it is on the main page (http://www.example.com/discover) ?

Comment: It'll be much easier if you build another view for this main page and keep the first view for the other pages... -Muhammad.